Ghosts stuck on a farm
I'm trying to find a movie I watched a few years back on tv. There's a farm where anyone who dies gets trapped as a ghost. 2 guys passing through have their car break down and get stuck there. One falls down a hill at the beginning and is not revealed to have died until the end. The farmer is who keeps the ghosts trapped there. And forces them to relive the moments leading up to their deaths. And it's either from Australia or New Zealand. 


The Locals (2003)

Grant is disconsolate following a split-up with his girlfriend. His
  best friend Paul persuades him to forget about things and come surfing
  with him for the weekend. 
They drive south from Auckland down into the Waikato countryside. But
  after taking a short cut, they become lost. They meet two girls who
  invite them come to a party, but instead they end up crashing off the
  road. 
Seeking help, they go to a farmhouse, only to see a man slashing a
  woman’s throat. They are spotted and then pursued by a group of armed
  locals. 
As they run for their lives, they find that their pursuers have the
  disconcerting ability to keep getting up again after they have been
  killed.
It’s the dead versus the living and an inescapable curse...

~ Synopsis edited from MORIA; Movie poster from NZ Film Commission
Read more about the movie here and watch the trailer here.

+1: Unfortunately, it looks like the OP has vanished so can't verify it, but this answer certainly seems to perfectly match the question.

Forgot I'd asked this here until I went looking up this movie again, but, yes, "The Locals" is the movie I was looking for. Thanks.
